# How to obtain Azure AD access token(to call Graph API), inside the Office 365 Outlook add-in?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, azure-ad-graph-api

I am building an Office 365 outlook add-in. From that add-in I want to call Graph API, is it possible to get the access token without asking user to login again for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has now made this possible. Right now its in preview and says its for "Desktop" only, which I'm not sure if that means Desktop Outlook and not Outlook Web, or maybe it just means not Outlook via mobile apps.

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

I still have yet to figure out how to actually implement the token exchange they discuss, but will update here if I find it.

Answer (score 2):

> > is it possible to get the access token without asking user to login again for the app?

No, you can’t.

In Outlook add-in, there is a JavaScript API called [getUserIdentityTokenAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#getUserIdentityTokenAsync). By calling this API, you can get an Exchange Identity token, but you cannot use this token to access the graph API.

To get the more information from exchange server in Outlook add-in, you can consider making a EWS request as an alternative way.

Here is a sample for your reference

[Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-MakeEWSRequest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-MakeEWSRequest)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single sing-on between an Office add-in and Graph API. You can use the approach from this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in.aspx). You will find how to minimize user actions during log in and cache refresh token to acquire access token in future.